# Images in RDLC from path stored in database

Tags: c#, database, report, rdlc, photo

I have an Articles table in the database with the fields ID, Name, Photo.  The Photo field is a string where the full path of the photo is stored.
I have a table in my report, I got all the fields loaded correctly but the photo field is empty. There is no error but photos are not shown.
External images are enabled, I have tried all the possible properties of the image in the report but no luck. I'm buildin C# Windows application.
Any idea?

I check all available solutions here an nothing works for me.
I have tried with parameter but still no luck. Also i need multiple photos from database.